# How can I use implicit conversions for two types that resolve to the same base type?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, type-alias

```
type JSON = String
type YAML = String

implicit def json2yaml(in:JSON):YAML = "some conversion"

val js:JSON = "some json"
val yml: YAML = js
```

The code above assigns "some json" to yml.  The implicit conversion is not used.  Is that because both YAML and JSON resolve to String?  Is there a way to make encourage the code to pick up the conversion?

Comment: Such directly - no, but of course you can always wrap them into case classes with string parameters and do it easily

Comment: Implicits conversions are a bad practice, now converting from two types that are the same seems like a great way to make code difficult to understand. What is wrong with adding just a `toYaml` extension method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that relationship between type and its *alias* is that of [equivalence](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#equivalence)

> If  is defined by a type alias `type  =` , then  is
>   equivalent to .

which means   and  are interchangeable in **all** contexts. When we define alias

```
type JSON = String
```

then `String` is not a "base" type of `JSON`, instead it **is** `JSON` itself. Thus

```
implicit def json2yaml(in: JSON): YAML = "some conversion"
```

is equivalent to

```
implicit def json2yaml(in: String): String = "some conversion"
```

which is why implicit conversion does not happen.

Instead of implicit conversion (which tends to be discouraged) consider *extension method* approach like so

```
case class Json(v: String)
case class Yaml(v: String)

implicit class JsonToJaml(json: Json) {
  def asYaml: Yaml = Yaml("some conversion which uses ${json.v}")
}

val js: Json = Json("some json")
val yml: Yaml = js.asYaml
```