# How to model a point?

Tags: scala, types

I'm trying to model a point with x and y coordinates.  I'd like to do it in such a way as to make it impossible to mix up the x and y values.

So, I came up with this:

```scala
package com.craigtreptow.scrayz

package object types {
  type X = Double
  type Y = Double
  type Point = (X,Y)
}
```

I then used it like this:

```
package com.craigtreptow.scrayz.types

object Main extends App {
  val x: X = 1.1
  val y: Y = 2.2

  val p: Point = (x, x)

  println(p)
}
```

I expected that to produce an error, but it worked:

```
~/c/scrayz(master|✚2…)> sbt run                      
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/Ctreptow/code/scrayz/project
[info] Loading settings for project scrayz from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to Scrayz (in build file:/Users/Ctreptow/code/scrayz/)
[info] running com.craigtreptow.scrayz.types.Main 
(1.1,1.1)
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Mar 9, 2020 6:08:49 PM
```

Is it possible to model a `Point` like this, such that the above code would produce a compiler error?

Comment: Modula 3 has (had?) branded types that made this very easy, but I assume that there are good reasons why this is not in Scala.

Comment: have a look at the newtype library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that given

```
type X = Double
type Y = Double
```

we have `X = Y`, that is, they are [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59462187/5205022) types. Perhaps wrap each coordinate in its own type

```
final case class X(v: Double) extends AnyVal
object X {
  implicit def doubleToX(x: Double): X = X(x)
}
final case class Y(v: Double) extends AnyVal
object Y {
  implicit def doubleToY(y: Double): Y = Y(y)
}
final case class Point(x: X, y: Y)

val x: X = 1.1
val y: Y = 2.2

val p: Point = Point(x, x) // Error: type mismatch; found: X required: Y
```

Note how `case class X(v: Double)` wraps the double into *specialised* semantic context where we know this double means X-axis coordinate, as opposed to *general* pure double which could take any number of meanings. Similar reasoning holds for modelling point as case class as opposed to pure tuple.

Comment: Thanks.  I remember seeing `case class` before, but how did you know to write `doubleToX` and `doubleToY` ?  Can you explain this code more, or point me to a resource that explains it?

Comment: @CraigTreptow [Implicit conversions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html) tend to be discouraged, but here it allows you to write `val x: X = 1.1` instead of `val x: X = X(1.1)` because former expands to `val x: X = doubleToX(1.1)`. There is no need to use it, personally I would not.